# Calculate the cheapest cost path from the source to destination using mass transit routes

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Problem statement**
Given a source, destination, and the bus arrival and departure times and routes, I want to find the least-cost path from the source to the destination. This may include taking a combination of buses and taxis to the destination. Buses have fixed timings but a taxi can be taken at any time between any two places

**Example**
For instance, my source is A, my destination is G. B, C are the relevant bus stations. 
1. My start time is 11:00. A bus leaves from A to B at 11:15 and arrives at B at 11:30 (cost=30).

2. A bus from A to C leaves at 11:15 and reaches C at 12:30 (cost=50).
3. A taxi from B to C arrives at C at  12:00(cost=100).
4. Bus from C to G leaves at 12:10 and arrives at 1:00 at G (cost=30).
5. Taxi from C to G costs 400 and a Taxi from A to G costs 600.

The cheapest solution is to take a bus from A to B, a taxi from B to C and a bus from C to G

**My approach** (Brute force is not an option here)

1. A greedy approach did not work here because optimal local decisions do not give a global optimal decision.
2. This problem looks a little like a weighted interval scheduling problem (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/weighted-job-scheduling/)) that can be solved using Dynamic Programming as the bus and taxi timings can be thought of as intervals. However, weighted interval scheduling involves maximizing the cost and if I try to minimize it the algorithm would stop prematurely. If I try to use negative costs and try to maximize then again the algorithm stops prematurely after adding just 1 interval.

Hence, Any advice on tackling this problem would be appreciated.